# VBA - Creating Word Document from Excel and Edit Certain Line to Contain Bold Text

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am looking to bold every second line entry on a word document that receives input from an excel spreadsheet. In other words, I want the resulting word document to have each line containing 'ID:' to contain bold text. I've looked into other examples but I keep getting errors such as mismatch.

```
Sub ExceltoWord_TestEnvironment()
    Dim wApp As Object
    Dim wDoc As Object
    Dim strSearchTerm
    Dim FirstMatch As Range
    Dim FirstAddress
    Dim intMyVal As String
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim strRowNoList As String
    Dim intPlaceHolder As Integer

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
wApp.Visible = True

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add

wDoc.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
wDoc.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

strSearchTerm = InputBox("Please enter the date to find", "Search criteria")


If strSearchTerm <> "" Then
    Set FirstMatch = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(strSearchTerm, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

        If FirstMatch Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "That date could not be found"
        Else

            FirstAddress = FirstMatch.Address
            intMyVal = strSearchTerm
            lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 'Search Column F, change as required.

        For Each cell In Range("F1:F" & lngLastRow) 'F is column
            If InStr(1, cell.Value, intMyVal) Then
                If strRowNoList = "" Then

                    strRowNoList = strRowNoList & cell.Row
                    intPlaceHolder = cell.Row

        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Group:             " & Cells(intPlaceHolder, 3) & vbNewLine
        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "ID:         " & Cells(intPlaceHolder, 2) & vbNewLine
        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Name:              " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
Else

                strRowNoList = strRowNoList & ", " & cell.Row
                intPlaceHolder = cell.Row

        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Group:             " & Cells(intPlaceHolder, 3) & vbNewLine
        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "ID:         " & Cells(intPlaceHolder, 2) & vbNewLine
        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Name:              " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

End If
            Next cell
            MsgBox strRowNoList

While Not FirstMatch Is Nothing
            Set FirstMatch = ActiveSheet.Cells.FindNext(FirstMatch)
        If FirstMatch.Address = FirstAddress Then
            Set FirstMatch = Nothing


        End If
        Wend
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Example:

Group: Group A

**ID:    123456**

Name: Jon Snow

Group: Group B

**ID:    789101**

Name: Samwell Tarly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a work around. Thought I would post it here to help others. Sorry my code isn't as clean as I would like it to be. Copying and pasting didn't quite match up.

```
Sub ExceltoWord_TestEnvironment()
    Dim wApp As Object
    Dim wDoc As Object
    Dim strSearchTerm
    Dim FirstMatch As Range
    Dim FirstAddress
    Dim intMyVal As String
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim strRowNoList As String
    Dim intPlaceHolder As Integer

Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wDoc = CreateObject("Word.Document")
wApp.Visible = True

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add

wDoc.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
wDoc.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

strSearchTerm = InputBox("Please enter the date to find", "Search criteria")


If strSearchTerm <> "" Then
    Set FirstMatch = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(strSearchTerm, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

        If FirstMatch Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "That date could not be found"
        Else

            FirstAddress = FirstMatch.Address
            intMyVal = strSearchTerm
            lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 'Search Column F, change as required.

        For Each cell In Range("F1:F" & lngLastRow) 'F is column
            If InStr(1, cell.Value, intMyVal) Then
                If strRowNoList = "" Then

                    strRowNoList = strRowNoList & cell.Row
                    intPlaceHolder = cell.Row
     intParaCount = wDoc.Paragraphs.Count

             i = 2
         Set objParagraph = wDoc.Paragraphs(i).Range
         With objParagraph
             .Font.Bold = True
         End With

        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Group:             " & Cells(intPlaceHolder, 3) & vbNewLine
        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "ID:         " & Cells(intPlaceHolder, 2) & vbNewLine
        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Name:              " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

         i = i + 4 'paragraph number

Else

                strRowNoList = strRowNoList & ", " & cell.Row
                intPlaceHolder = cell.Row

        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Group:             " & Cells(intPlaceHolder, 3) & vbNewLine
        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "ID:         " & Cells(intPlaceHolder, 2) & vbNewLine
        wDoc.Content.InsertAfter "Name:              " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

            i = i + 4

End If
            Next cell
            MsgBox strRowNoList

While Not FirstMatch Is Nothing
            Set FirstMatch = ActiveSheet.Cells.FindNext(FirstMatch)
        If FirstMatch.Address = FirstAddress Then
            Set FirstMatch = Nothing


        End If
        Wend
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

The code utilizes .paragraphs() where 'i' is the paragraph you want to bold:

```
   i = 2
     Set objParagraph = wDoc.Paragraphs(i).Range
     With objParagraph
         .Font.Bold = True
     End With
```

And the difference in paragraphs is added after each iteration

```
i = i + 4 'paragraph number
```